# Why do image size differ when vertical vs horizontal?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Tried to create a random image with PIL as per the example:

```
import numpy
from PIL import image

a = numpy.random.rand(48,84)
img = Image.fromarray(a.astype('uint8')).convert('1')
print(len(img.tobytes()))
```

This particular code will output 528.
Wen we flip the numbers of the numpy array:

```
a = numpy.random.rand(84,48)
```

The output we get is 504.
Why is that?

I was expecting for the byte number to be the same, since the numpy arrays are the same size.

Comment: You aren't actually getting the size of a Numpy array - you are getting the size of `img` which is a `PIL Image`.

Comment: @mark yeah, but that's kind of beside the point because in this case the `PIL.Image` object represents a boolean array (a "bilevel image") with the same dimensions as the original numpy array

Comment: @Noah My point is that the Numpy arrays have the same length in bytes as each other. The lengths only differ precisely because OP is getting length of a `PIL Image` not the length of a Numpy array.

Comment: @Mark I assumed OP understood they weren't getting the size of the numpy array but rather the PIL Image. But it is worth noting that what I described only applies to PIL images in mode 1, not to numpy arrays of bools which are encoded 1 byte per element.

Comment: @Mark, my point was precisely regarding the PIL.Image and not the Numpy array. I understood that the Numpy arrays had the same size, and that was why I was expecting the PIL.Image objects to be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `tobytes()` on the boolean array*, the data is likely encoded per row. In your second example, there are 48 booleans in each row of `img`. So each row can be represented with 6 bytes (48 bits). 6 bytes * 84 rows = 504 bytes in `img`. However, in your first example, there are 84 pixels per row, which is not divisible by 8. In this case, the encoder represents each row with 11 bytes (88 bits). There are 4 extra bits of padding per row. So now the total size is 11 bytes * 48 rows = 528 bytes.

If you test a bunch of random input shapes for a 2d boolean array to encode, you will find that when the number of elements per row is divisible by 8, the number of total bytes in the encoding is equal to the width * height / 8. However, when the row length is not divisible by 8, the encoding will contain more bytes because it has to pad each row with between 1 and 7 bits.

In summary - ideally, we would want to store eight boolean values per byte, but this is complicated by the fact that the row length isn't always divisible by 8, and the encoder serializes the array *by row*.

**Edit for clarification**: *the `PIL.Image` object in mode "1" (binary or "bilevel" image) effectively represents a boolean array. In mode 1, the original image (in this case, the numpy array `a`) is thresholded to convert it to a binary image.